# Mail send by xpages form change group by user of group in sendTo field

Tags: email, xpages, sendto

I developed an application that has a form where this form once completed is sent by e-mail as the list of selected group or user in the container. The problem is that when I choose to send e-mail to a group and click on the submit button, check the box to the e-mail client for lotus note that does not appear the group name but the name of all users in that group I selected. Anyone know why this happens? That is, when I choose a group and sending e-mail, Lotus internally changes the name of the group by the name of all users of this group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try adding field `$ExpandGroups` with a value of `0` to the document. See [this](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21086738)  for detailed information on this field.

Comment: I just insert this line: docEmail.appendItemValue("$ExpandGroups", "0") and works.

Answer (score 1):

Is the group a personal group? In other words, is it in the user's local address book? If so, it has to expand it to the members because the router won't be able to find the group name in the Domino Directory.

Comment: No, the application is getting the list of groups directly from the server. Turns out the router for some reason changes the SendTo field entered the users in the group and not the group name after the command "doc.send (group)" is executed.

Comment: yes, I've tried this possibility. To send e-mail I was using an agent written in Java, when I realized this problem, rewritten agent in lotus script, but without success. Then I tried to test manually enter the group name in the command parameter "doc.send (" hard code group ") and had no success. My next attempt will not use the agent and send the e-mail by writing directly in javascript on the server side. what do you think might be happening? Recalling the list of groups come by the server, then the group actually exists on the server, but for some reason the router is replacing.